# Does adding a lot of release (and tags) with custom uploaded asset files makes git file size bigger?

Tags: git, github, github-api

So we have a pipeline where if we have some changes with the code we will create a release with incremental version and upload a .zip and .tar.gz file. This is all done using github api.

Normally, we create these release around at least 5 times a week. That means that the number of releases and tags will grow exponentially.

Was wondering if this will make the file size of the git grow bigger, just worried that maybe a few years from now doing git clone or even pull will make it so if the file size grows bigger. Also, not really sure how git works internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will, it you are adding and committing and pushing binary files to the (GitHub-hosted) Git repository itself.

It will not, if you are adding those to [GitHub release assets](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-releases)

> We don't limit the total size of your binary release files, nor the bandwidth used to deliver them. However, each individual file must be under 2 GB in size.

The Git repository itself, in the latter case, won't be any bigger to clone if you add many releases.

Comment: does this mean that even if we add a lot of tags it will still not make the file size bigger?

Comment: @mateeyow Yes, adding tons of tags won't increase much if any the size of the repository itself.

Comment: Sorry, another question. Does creating releases and uploading assets makes the git clone slow? Somehow, cloning the repository with multiple tags takes some time. Not really sure how git works.

Comment: @mateeyow No: release and assets are metadata managed by GitHub alone. When you clone the Git repository hosted by GitHub, you are not cloning its GitHub assets.

Comment: Okay thanks. Then this is an entirely different issue.

Comment: @mateeyow Yes: you could ask a new question detailing the issue with more details (OS, Git version, time spent cloning a repository, ...)